# Item information for calendar_item

Tags: exchangelib

I'm working with calendar information in the XML response from the MS server. I successfully extract fields from CalendarItem, but I also need some of the fields from CalendarItem's ancestor, Item. The response from the server contains that information in xml, so I believe I can use "from_xml" to get, for example, the "item:TextBody".

If "from_xml" is the right approach, how should I use it? If I'm on the wrong path, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you attempting to do? exchangelib makes all values in the XML available as attributes on the returned items. There are lots of examples in the documentation.

`CalendarItem` is a subclass of `Item` so the fields on the superclass are also available to the subclass. You can see all available fields by renting `CalendarItem.FIELDS`.